# After moving to another Team Foundatio Server, I get System.Web.HttpException: 'Response is not available in this context.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpcontext, urlhelper

The code works on our live and development website but when I try to run locally either against my local or development database, I get the error:  System.Web.HttpException: 'Response is not available in this context.'

I've tried running a past release that I KNOW works. This only started happening when our code was moved to a new Team Foundation Server.  I'm beginning to wonder if this is a setting in Visual Studio's.  I used a Watch window and verified the correct information is being passed for the area, action and controller.  The URL's that are not null work correctly.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
/// <summary>
        /// Returns the URL for this link
        /// </summary>
        [NotMapped]
        public string trueUrl
        {
            get
            {
                if (url != null)
                    return url;

                if (HttpContext.Current != null)
                {
                    var urlhelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                    return urlhelper.Action(action, controller, new { area = area });
                }

                return "ERROR";
            }
        }
```

This causes the error: System.Web.HttpException: 'Response is not available in this context.'

I need help on where to look to begin to solve this.

Comment: do you import all packets via nugets? also which version of .net are you using?

Comment: Yes, packets are imported via nugets.